# Multiprocessing in python won't keep log of errors in log file

Tags: python, error-handling, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've implemented multiprocessing in a data analysis I'm running but sometimes there are errors and instead of having the entire que get killed I wanted them to just be ignored so I implemeneted a try statement.  But new errors keep cropping up, is there a more exhaustive list of erros I can include in the except statement?  In general I'd just like errors to be logged and then the code to move on.

Secondly though, the errors are not getting logged in the log file I'm making.  Not sure why.  This is an example of my code, I've replaced the analysis in teh try statement with some simpler steps.  More or less does the same thing, takes the data and writes an output to a csv for each dataset a process is running on (here represented with the dictionary of dataframes).   NOTE:  I have purposely introduced a keyerror here by misnaming one of the columns in the second dataframe.

**Example code...**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging
import traceback
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process

output_dir = ''
input_dir = 'df_folder'

# make our data
    # Create a dict of 5 dataframes with 3 columns of ten entries each
    df_dict = {i: pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) for i in range(5)}
    # Introduce an error by changing a column name in one of the dataframes
    df_dict[1].columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'wrong_col']

for key, df in df_dict.items():
    file_name = f"{key}_df.csv"
    file_path = os.path.join(input_dir, file_name)
    df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

   
# define funditons for mutiprocessing and error logging...
def listener_process(queue):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='abi_detector_app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    while True:
        message = queue.get()
        if message == 'kill':
            break
        logging.error(message)



def example_process(df_id, queue):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"{input_dir}/{df_id}_df.csv")
    try:
        for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
            mean = df[col].mean()
            std = df[col].std()
            result = pd.DataFrame({'mean': [mean], 'std': [std]}, index=[col])
            result.to_csv(f'{output_dir}/df_{df_id}_{col}_stats.csv')
    except (IndexError, KeyError) as e:
        logging.error('Error in dataframe id: %s', df_id)
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())



manager = Manager()
queue = manager.Queue()
listener = Process(target=listener_process, args=(queue,))
listener.start()


pool_size = 5
df_list = df_dict.keys()
# run the processes with the specified number of cores

# new code which passes the error messages to the listener process
with Pool(pool_size) as p:
    p.starmap(example_process, [(df_id, queue) for df_id in df_list])

queue.put('kill')
listener.join()
```

**NOTE** df_dict is a place holder for what my script is actually doing.  I editted the example so that it is written to file as a folder which stores the generated dataframes as csv's.  Then example process loads them. This is a better example of whats happening because df_dict really does not need to be shared across processes.  Just the error logging file.

Comment: Using `multiprocessing`-subprocesses, each subprocess (`listener_process`) needs to initialize it's own logger - the logger configuration is not inherited from the main process. Notice that several processes writing to the same logfile will produce garbage, so you'll want to log into a buffer and return the log to the main process for replay, or log to a separate file.
Side note: Use context-managers for all things multiprocessing!

Comment: I'm not sure how to iplement this, could you provide a simple example below?

Comment: you can use `except Exception as e:`, all exceptions that you should catch inherit from `Exception`.

Comment: I don't see where function `example_process` is being referenced.

Comment: AH yes sorry my mistake

Comment: I fixed the code if any of the commentators want to provide an answer so I can close the question that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code based on the [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes).

**Update**

The code executes successfully whether the platform is Unix-like, which by default uses the *fork* method of starting new processes, or Windows, which must use the *spawn* method of starting new processes.

We would like the code that creates the dataframes to be executed once. If that code is at global scope but not within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, then under Windows each pool process will be re-creating the dataframes. This could be inefficient depending on the complexity of the code. Moreover, the code is using a random number generator to create the dataframes and this would result in each pool process creating dataframes with different data, which could be a problem. Therefore, we need to ensure that the dataframe-creation code is executed only once by the main process and initialized in each pool process once using a pool initializer function. This technique will work whether we are running under Windows or Linux. However, if we are running under Linux or some other platform that supports the *fork* method of creating processes,  then it is generally more efficient to allow the pool processes to *inherit* the dataframes from the main process rather than passing the dataframes to a pool initializer. The following code now checks to see if we can use the fork method and if so allows the pool processes to inherit the dataframes. A pool initializer is still used to initialize the multiprocessing log handling for each process that will be logging messages.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging
import logging.handlers
import traceback
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Process, set_start_method

def listener_process(queue):
    root = logging.getLogger()
    h = logging.FileHandler('abi_detector_app.log', mode='w')
    f = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    h.setFormatter(f)
    root.addHandler(h)

    while True:
        try:
            record = queue.get()
            if record is None:  # We send this as a sentinel to tell the listener to quit.
                break
            logger = logging.getLogger(record.name)
            logger.handle(record)  # No level or filter logic applied - just do it!
        except Exception:
            print('Whoops! Problem:', file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)


def init_pool(*args):
    queue = args[0]
    h = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue)  # Just the one handler needed
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(h)
    # send all messages, for demo; no other level or filter logic applied.
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    if len(args) == 2:
        # We have additionally been past the dataframes because they could not
        # be inherited.
        global df_dict

        df_dict = args[1]


output_dir = ''

def example_process(df_id):
    df = df_dict[df_id]
    try:
        for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
            mean = df[col].mean()
            std = df[col].std()
            result = pd.DataFrame({'mean': [mean], 'std': [std]}, index=[col])
            result.to_csv(f'{output_dir}/df_{df_id}_{col}_stats.csv')
        logging.debug(f'Processing complete for id {df_id}.')
    except Exception:  # Catch all possible exceptions
        logging.error('Error in dataframe id: %s', df_id)
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # If we can use the fork method of starting new processes, then the pool processes
    # can inherit the dataframes from the main process, which is normally more efficient
    # than passing the dataframes to each pool process using the pool initializer.
    try:
        set_start_method('fork')
    except:
        using_fork = False
    else:
        using_fork = True

    # Create a dict of 5 dataframes with 3 columns of ten entries each.
    # We are ensuring that the code to create the dataframes is only executed once (by
    # the main process):
    df_dict = {i: pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) for i in range(5)}
    # Introduce an error by changing a column name in one of the dataframes
    df_dict[1].columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'wrong_col']

    queue = Queue()
    listener = Process(target=listener_process, args=(queue,))
    listener.start()

    pool_size = 5
    df_list = df_dict.keys()
    # run the processes with the specified number of cores

    # Can the pool processes inherit the dataframes or must we pass them
    # to each pool process?
    pool_initargs = (queue,) if using_fork else (queue, df_dict)

    # new code which passes the error messages to the listener process
    with Pool(pool_size, initializer=init_pool, initargs=pool_initargs) as p:
        p.map(example_process, df_list)

    #queue.put('kill')
    queue.put(None) # Use None as the seninel
    listener.join()
```

**The contents of *abi_detector_app.log*:**

```None
root - DEBUG - Processing complete for id 0.
root - ERROR - Error in dataframe id: 1
root - ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'col3'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 46, in example_process
    mean = df[col].mean()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3455, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'col3'

root - DEBUG - Processing complete for id 2.
root - DEBUG - Processing complete for id 3.
root - DEBUG - Processing complete for id 4.
```

**Update 2**

Since you have updated your question, I have modified my answer to conform with your new requirements. Note that the following code only works on platforms using the *fork* method for creating processes. You can see the previous update to see how you would modify the code to be cross-platform compatible. Also, please see my added comments to your code; they have the string *(Booboo)* so that you can easily search for them.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging
import logging.handlers
import traceback
# Use a multiprocessing queue instead of a managed queue (Booboo):
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Process
# Add missing import (Booboo):
import os

output_dir = ''
input_dir = 'df_folder'

# make our data
# Corrected indentation problem (Booboo)
# Create a dict of 5 dataframes with 3 columns of ten entries each
df_dict = {i: pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) for i in range(5)}
# Introduce an error by changing a column name in one of the dataframes
df_dict[1].columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'wrong_col']

for key, df in df_dict.items():
    file_name = f"{key}_df.csv"
    file_path = os.path.join(input_dir, file_name)
    df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

def init_pool(queue):
    h = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue)  # Just the one handler needed
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(h)
    # send all messages, for demo; no other level or filter logic applied.
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def listener_process(queue):
    root = logging.getLogger()
    h = logging.FileHandler('abi_detector_app.log', mode='w')
    f = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    h.setFormatter(f)
    root.addHandler(h)

    while True:
        message = queue.get()
        if message == 'kill':
            break
        logger = logging.getLogger(message.name)
        logger.handle(message)

# There is no point in passing queue to this worker function
# since it is not used (Booboo):
def example_process(df_id):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"{input_dir}/{df_id}_df.csv")
    try:
        for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
            mean = df[col].mean()
            std = df[col].std()
            result = pd.DataFrame({'mean': [mean], 'std': [std]}, index=[col])
            result.to_csv(f'{output_dir}/df_{df_id}_{col}_stats.csv')
    except (IndexError, KeyError) as e:
        logging.error('Error in dataframe id: %s', df_id)
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())

# A multiprocessing.Queue will offer better performance than a
# managed queue (Booboo):
queue = Queue()
listener = Process(target=listener_process, args=(queue,))
listener.start()

pool_size = 5
df_list = df_dict.keys()
# run the processes with the specified number of cores:
with Pool(pool_size, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(queue,)) as p:
    # There is no point in passing queue to this worker function
    # since it is not used (Booboo):
    p.map(example_process, df_list)

queue.put('kill')
listener.join()
```

Contents of log file:

```None
root - ERROR - Error in dataframe id: 1
root - ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Booboo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'col3'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Booboo/test/test.py", line 52, in example_process
    mean = df[col].mean()
  File "/home/Booboo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/Booboo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'col3'
```

Comment: I think the server I'm on is running linux.  Is there anything in here that would cause problems?

Comment: The code should work on Windows or Linux.

Comment: I have added an update that provides additional information as far as cross-platform compatibility. If you are satisfied with this answer, then consider *accepting* it.

Comment: You didn't have to update it thank you for doing that, sorry for the delay I just wanted to try it before accepting it.  Was doing other stuff before come back to this code.  thank you =)

Comment: I think the only thing I need to change is the pool_initargs = (queue,) if using_fork else (queue, df_dict).  For me I can just leave it out.  My actualy code is calling data from an online repository for each process.  The dataframes are not stored locally so it doesn't need that tuple of args.  Just a list of id's to call stuff from an api running in each process.

Comment: I tried the code out, and it works for the error logging but on my end I screwed up in my example because having all of df_dict loaded in memory is not what is happening in my real code.  THere is too much data to do that, instead I call the data in each process from an api then I load it from the cache on the hard disk.  SO the data itself has no need to be shared across processes as was the case in the previous example.  I updated my example to represent this.

Comment: Yes, but that really has nothing to do with your original problem which was how does one do logging with multiprocessing. So does whether you are sharing data or not have any bearing on my answer?

Comment: I didn't think it would but I've tried to fuse your answer to my original code and it's causing an error.  Your code loads the data with the queue so it's causing problems I'm tyring to debug it now so it works with my og code but having issues.

My original post also was kind of a bad example because of this oversight on my part so I changed it.  I think most people doing this would not be loading all their data into shared memory, so the error logging should be seperate from it.

Comment: You just need to modify init_pool to take a single queue argument and when you create the pool you only pass the queue as the *initargs* tuple.

Comment: Ah ok that may be the issue, I was trying to pass the df id list (well the equivalent variable) to the initargs tuple

Comment: I changed the init_pool function, removed the if statement in it.  I pass this...
pool_initargs = (queue,) if using_fork else (queue) but now this seems to have created an infinite loop.  I get an error from Process ForkPoolWorker-3749 which is... TypeError: __main__.init_pool() argument after * must be an iterable, not Queue

This error just gets repeated adinifintum for like 20 minutes until it gets killed by the server.  If I try to pass  pool_initargs = (queue,) then nothing runs due to this other error... TypeError: process_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queue'

Comment: I don't think its as simple as not passing the dict_id list.

Comment: `(queue)` is not a `tuple` - you are missing a comma. It should just be `pool_initargs = (queue,)` (better yet, just do `with pool(..., initargs=(queue,)) as p:` and get rid of the `pool_initargs` variable altogether.

Comment: I have added a second update just so there is no confusion as to what you need to get your code to work.

Comment: Working as intended thank you very much.